# getting last forum poster on a complex query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

I am building a forum for an application and I am stuck trying to get the latest poster on a discussion. The database I am using is Oracle.

I have the following tables:

```
discussions
    id 
    course_id
    user_id
    title
    stub
    created_at

threads
   id
   discussion_id
   user_id
   created_at
   updated_at
   message

 discussion_views
     discussion_id
     user_id
     time

 users
     id
     username
```

And I have the following query:

```
select discussions.created_at, 
       discussions.title, 
       users.username, 
       count(threads.id) AS "replies", 
       count(distinct discussion_views.discussion_id) AS "views" 
 from discussions
 left join threads on discussions.id=threads.discussion_id
 left join discussion_views on discussions.id=discussion_views.discussion_id
 join users on users.id=discussions.user_id
 group by discussions.created_at, discussions.title, users.username
 order by discussions.created_at desc
```

What I need is to get the last user who posted in a thread and the date. Should I make an inner insert, a join or should I make another insert. I also want my query to be performant because my forum will need to handle a lot of traffic.

Comment: You have asked for the date of the last user who posted in a thread, but your threads table doesn't have a date on it. Also, your "views" count will always return 1 (where there have been any views), because for a given discussion there will only ever be one distinct discussion_id - does `discussion_views` have its own unique `id` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select * from
(select discussions.created_at, 
        discussions.title, 
        users.username as discussion_created_by, 
        count(distinct threads.id) over (partition by discussions.created_at, 
                                                      discussions.title, 
                                                      users.username) AS replies, 
        count(distinct discussion_views.time) 
             over (partition by discussions.created_at, 
                                discussions.title, 
                                users.username) AS "views",
        threads.user_id AS latest_post_by,
        threads.updated_at AS latest_post_at,
        row_number() over (partition by discussions.created_at, 
                                        discussions.title, 
                                        users.username
                           order by threads.id desc) AS rn
 from discussions
 left join threads on discussions.id=threads.discussion_id
 left join discussion_views on discussions.id=discussion_views.discussion_id
 join users on users.id=discussions.user_id) sq
where rn=1
order by created_at desc
```

Comment: it is not working...here is the error `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

Comment: @Mythriel: Due to a missing comma after `"views"`, now corrected. I notice that although you have updated the table structures, you haven't added a unique ID to `discussion_views`, so I have amended the query to use `time` instead. Try the updated query.

Comment: can u explain pls a little the query..i get strange data for latest post by, i mean i get nothing even tho i have data for it

Comment: i have a mysql background, this is my first application using oracle

Comment: @Mythriel: What do you want explaining? If `latest_post_by` and `latest_post_at` are both null, this probably means that there no threads for that discussion, while if `latest_post_by` is null but `latest_post_at` has a value then it probably means that the user_id is null on the latest thread for the discussion.

Comment: yes ok, i got it, but why is the query not returning correct data for last thread author and time(last_post_by, last_post_at)

Comment: @Mythriel: Because there is no data to return. Try adding some sample data to your question. `rn` is a column alias for the row_number expression.

Comment: it is working now but I can not manage to make the query get the last poster username not it's id...can u help with this?